# perl: More concise way to branch based on whether split succeeded?

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing, split

I know split returns the number of fields parsed, if it assigned to a scalar; and returns an array if assigned to an array.

Is there a way to check whether a line is successfully parsed without having to call split twice (once to check how many fields were parsed, and, if the correct number of fields were parsed, a second time to return the fields in an array)?

```
foreach (@lines) {

  if ( split ) {
    my ($ipaddr, $hostname) = split;
  }

}
```

.. I need to check whether the split succeeded in order to avoid later uninitialized references to $ipaddr and $hostname. Just seems like I ought to be able to combine the two calls to split into a single call.

Comment: *Please change your username to something we can type without checking each character one at a time.*

Comment: @Borodin there's the tab autocomplete. Does that not work for you? This one at least picked a name and a picture and isn't just _user123123123_. :)

Comment: @Simbabque: Not on the tablet that I have to use most of the time. In any case, I think it's bad manners to select a username that is unpronounceable. `123123123` I can at least pronounce and type without constantly referring back. I wonder why anyone would want to change their default username `user9999999` assigned by SO to something like this.

Comment: @B good point about the tablet. My phone keyboard's autocomplete has _@Borodin_, _@ikegami_ and a few others from around here when I type an _@_. (It also has a bunch of Ingress screen names because that uses the same syntax in its chat). What I do is just type the first letter. That's enough for SO to highlight if there is only one person with a name starting with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
foreach (@lines) {
  if (2 == (my ($ipaddr, $hostname) = split)) {
    # Got exactly two fields
  }
}
```

So if you just want to skip bad lines, you can simply use:

```
foreach (@lines) {
  2 == (my ($ipaddr, $hostname) = split)
    or next;

  # Got exactly two fields
}
```

Don't forget to remove trailing whitespace from your lines first (such as by using `chomp` to remove line feeds) or it will mess up your field count.

You can change the `==` to `<=` if there might be more fields.

Comment: This relies on using the list assignment operator in scalar context, which returns the number of values to which its RHS evaluated. [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) explains the two different assignment operators and what they return in each context.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would prefer a regex match:

```
for ( @lines ) {

    next unless my ($ipaddr, $hostname) = /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;

    # use $ipaddr & $hostname

}
```

This is different from the original in that it will succeed if *more than* two non-space substrings are found, but a fix is simple if it is necessary.